# How to save entire Docker content into tar file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-container, docker-image

I tried to install a Ubuntu machine using the Docker command

```
docker run -it --name mymachine ubuntu
```

In that Ubuntu machine, I have installed the following applications

1. Java
2. Unzip
3. SSH

And then I performed Docker commit operation `docker commit mymachine copymachine`. Now if I run this copy image in a new container means it working perfectly. But in my case, I'm trying to  save that image file using the "save" command:

```
docker save copymachine > MachineInfo.tar
```

And then forwarding this tar file to my another machine and trying to load this image in that Docker using the following command

```
docker load MachineInfo.tar updatedmachine
```

If I try to run this image in a container and trying to access the application installed on the previous machine container.

But none of the applications were been showing in the newly created container.

Comment: save/load work with images. If you want to work with containers, you need export/import.

Comment: You should never install software in a running container: it will be lost as soon as the container exits.  Docker has a [sample application](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/) tutorial that walks through the standard process of building and running a custom image; that's the normal way to get software installed in a reusable image.

Comment: @halfer - save + export also work with images. But that’s a bad idea, because you lose the original image’s metadata, its change history, and any savings customers might get when they download images with the same lower levels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inlined with @ halfer comment, You need to perform simple export and import. Please perform the following steps.

1. Start the container

```
docker run -it --name mymachine ubuntu /bin/bash
```

2. Update and install the jdk

```
apt update
apt install default-jre
```

3. Validate that java is up and accessible

```
java -version
```

4. Export the image to tar from another command line. First, do a docker ps and note down the container id of the container in which you have installed java, lets say it is 4719ab149ee2. Export the container into a tar using the command.

```
docker export 4719ab149ee2  > mymachine.tar
```

5. Stop the container.

```
docker stop <container_id>
```

6. Remove the ubuntu image from your local registry by executing the following commands.

```
docker images
dokcer image rm <image_id>
```

7. Now import the image from the tar file using the command.

```
C:\Users\ameena>docker import - mymachine <  mymachine.tar
```

8. Now check that image has been imported into your local registry by executing the command.

```
docker images
```

9. Now create a container from this image using the command.

```
docker run -it --name mymachinefromimage mymachine:latest /bin/bash
```

10. Now check that java is present by using the command.

```
java --version
```

Note: Step 5,6,7,8,9 are validation steps.